# Hardhat testing on testnet (Rinkeby)

Tags: ethereumjs, testnets, testing, hardhat

I want to do some final tests on a smart contract that has been deployed on the Rinkeby testnet.
I am trying to run the below script (saved in my hardhat test folder) with hardhat but get the following error *"1) Should return the project Name and ID once it's deployed"* when I run npx hardhat test --network rinkeby in the console.

Note that my hardhat.config.js file is configured correctly since I could deploy the contract on the Rinkeby testnet with hardhat.

if I replace provider by the addressed which deployed the contract I get the same error.
Am I doing something incorrect in the way the contract instance is declared in the script file (using ether.js) ?

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("DesignManager", function () {
  it("Should return the project Name and ID once it's deployed", async function () {    

    //const DesignManager = await ethers.getContractFactory("DesignManager");

    const abi = [ { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [ { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "previousOwner", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "newOwner", "type": "address" } ], "name": "OwnershipTransferred", "type": "event" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "owner", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" } ], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "renounceOwnership", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "newOwner", "type": "address" } ], "name": "transferOwnership", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" } ];

    const designManager = new ethers.Contract(0x60D70e76eF9158F1bBDC829f4b3CbabeAadF0F86, abi, provider);

    expect(await designManager.projectName()).to.equal("Project1");
    expect(await designManager.projectID()).to.equal("01");

  });
});
```

Comment: There must be an error listing below the test results, please include it, you just ut the name of the test that is failing, but at the end it lists the errors of the failed tests cases.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, please see below the errors of the failed test cases:
0 passing (22s)
 2 failing

Comment: 1) DesignManager
       Should return the project Name and ID once it's deployed:
     Error: invalid signer or provider (argument="signerOrProvider", value=1.364023963139541e+47, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.5.0)
      at Logger.makeError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:225:28)
      at Logger.throwError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:237:20)
      at Logger.throwArgumentError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:241:21)
      at Contract.BaseContract (node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/src.ts/index.ts:668:20)

Comment: at new Contract (node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:1047:42)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/DesignManager_3D-test_rinkeby.js:12:27)


  2) DesignManager
       Should return the project Name and ID once it's deployed:
     Error: Timeout of 20000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/Users/tristanw/Desktop/UNSW/Papers/Paper 2 - BCDT Architecture/code/test/DesignManager_3D.js)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)

Comment: I think the issue must be coming from the way I define the provider:
I currently have:
`const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();`
how can I modify this statement to use the Rinkeby network (note that I am using alchemy api) ?

Comment: I also tried:
`let provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider('rinkeby');`
and it returned unidentified variable when I tried to console.log some contracts state variable. Any idea why I can't read that Rinkeby contract from hardhat?

Comment: Why does it needs to be tested against rinkeby? why dont you just test the contract itself ? You have the abi so I dont see why would you grab a deployed contract instead of deploying the contract on the test scope and test that

Comment: I want to test it on the Rinkeby because the contract is doing some API calls with Chainlink and I want to test how this works in real web based conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing your tests in Mocha/Jest framework.
Write the above code in a separate script and run it using `hardhat run scripts/<yourscriptname> --network rinkeby`.

Please note that you will have to remove `expect`/`describe` and all functions related to mocha framework. Use simple `assert` functions in your testing script.

Comment: This answer needs to explain WHY